# Display list of files in current view path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a view folder like this: `app/views/pages/tests/*`. Within that folder are several sub-folders and an `index.html.slim`. In the `index.html.slim` file, I want to auto-generate a list of links to all the sub-folders. I'm not sure how to start though, as I don't know how to get the current view's path from within the view file.

*Edit:*

I should mention that these view files are being served similarly to thoughtbot's [High Voltage gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage), i.e. everything in `app/views/pages/*` is served by the PagesController. If no matching routes are found, we take the requested route, send it to the PagesController, and serve up the corresponding view file in the `app/views/pages` directory. So `http://localhost:3000/tests/a/` would load  `app/views/pages/tests/a/index.html.slim`. Effectively the PagesController has become a static file server.

So within some of these 'static' directories, I'd like to print out the directory contents. I need to find a dynamic way of determining the currently served view's path, and then grab all the files in that path to output them.

This is a pretty specific use-case, but I was wondering if there were any general ways of determining a view's path from within the view, so I could do something like this:

```
ul
  - current_view_directory.files.each do |file|
    li = link_to file, file.path
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic belongs in the controller, not the view.

Pseudocode:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  def index
    dir = Rails.root.join('app', 'views', 'pages', 'tests').to_s
    @subdirs = Dir.glob("#{dir}/**/*").select{|f| File.directory? f}
  end
```

Your edit describes wanting to serve various static pages from the same controller.

Pseudocode:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    static_page_key = params[…] # edit this line to work with your routing
    dir = Rails.root.join('app', 'views', 'pages', static_page_key).to_s
    @subdirs = Dir.glob("#{dir}/**/*").select{|f| File.directory? f}
  end
```

Comment: That works, but I was hoping to find a more dynamic solution. The controller serves all my static pages, so hardwiring to 'pages/tests' won't work for other view directories.

Comment: Ok, describe more of your goal, and I'll add more to my question. The controller is definitely the right place for what you're asking.